# React-Native deeplinking if app is closed doesn't work ( React-Navigation v5)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have implemented deep links for my app with React Navigation V5.

I have a problem regarding Deep Linking. If the app is closed(killed) and it is opened via a deep link it will take me to the home screen rather than the screen it has to take me to.

Here's my linking config, from what I've read in the docs ([here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#third-party-integrations)), i'm passing the URL from the `getInitialUrl` function to the subscribe and here
`const onReceiveURL = ({ url }) => listener(url);`
it should parse the URL to a valid navigation state and take me to the screen it has to.  I might be mistaken with how subscribe works, though.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['appName://', 'app.appName.com://', APP_WEB_DOMAIN],
    async getInitialURL() {
      // Check if app was opened from a deep link
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      if (url != null) {
        return url;
      }
    },
    subscribe(listener) {
      const onReceiveURL = ({ url }) => listener(url);

      Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);

      return () => {
        // Clean up the event listener
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
      };
    },
    config: {
      screens: {
        SignInScreen: 'login',
        UnauthenticatedStack: '',
        TrackListScreen: 'playlist/:id/' //:id gets parsed as a string, you have to specify it if you want a number.
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you post what your `NavigationContainer` looks like

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (deep link from push notification) due to a bug in react-native-splash-screen

have a look here https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-splash-screen-demo/pull/11

Comment: Would this be available for this [package](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) ?